# Error al cargar valores a un ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Tengo un problema a la hora de generar un reporte, el reporte necesita parámetros además de conocer el valor del reporte asignado.

Este es el *código* que tengo hasta ahora pero me sale error:

```
ReportViewer1.Reset();
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[1];
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter(documento.Text.ToString());

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "AsistenciaPersonal.rptHorariosPersonal.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
report.Name = "HorarioDocentesDataSet";
report.Value = new HorarioDocentesDataSetTableAdapters.buscaHorarioDocenteTableAdapter();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(report);
```

El error aparece en la línea `report.Value`, el error que me arroja es el siguiente:

> El objeto de origen de datos del informe debe ser de tipo `System.Data.DataTable`, `System.Collections.IEnumerable` o `System.Web.UI.IDataSource`.

Comment: como declaras `report` ? y que contiene esta clase `HorarioDocentesDataSetTableAdapters`

Comment: ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar este problema?